# Insert Table in Excel using win32com and Python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am generating multiple excel files and exporting dataframes to various tabs. I'd like to 'insert table' (ctrl+t in excel) for one of the tabs and cont working in the same file. ...any advice on how to do that?
I don't want to create a new workbook object by using workbooks.open() since i'm in the middle of the process. I cannot use xlsxwriter or openpyxl and win32com is preferred. i'm stuck...any help and example would be appreciated.

Comment: Look into xlwings.  It uses the win32 api to drive Excel from Python.

Comment: thank you I think I found a way using xlwings

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to open a new Workbook with win32com, you can just use the currently active Workbook(s) like so:

```
import win32.com.client as win32

xl = win32.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks("WorkbookName")
```

I believe you can also iterate over xl.Workbooks.